# Regular Expression Extractor extracted a value from Response but when i used the value into further requests space is attached at last

Tags: regex, jmeter

Response:
{"negotiateVersion":0,"connectionId":"h4i-RFWmLx9ctVB5LcAmZA","availableTransports":[{"transport":"ServerSentEvents","transferFormats":["Text"]},{"transport":"LongPolling","transferFormats":["Text","Binary"]}]}

Have to extract **connection id** for my further requests

[image]

[image]

Comment: How to pass the above extracted value without space at last into further requests. Attached the screenshot where passing the extracted value into another request and space is included at last

Comment: "connectionId":"(.*?)[^\s]" you can use this to remove space at end or you can use \S instead of [^\s] to avoid white spaces at end

Comment: How do you construct your request? Maybe there's a stray space in one of the text fields

Answer (score 2):

[JSON is not a regular language](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/4017) therefore using regular expressions for extracting data from JSON responses is not the best idea.

JMeter provides:

1. [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) allowing using [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) language, the relevant expression will be `$.connectionId`

   [image]
2. [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-json-jmespath-extractor-andassertion-a-guide) allowing using [JMESPath](https://jmespath.org/) language, the relevant expression will be just `connectionId`

   [image]

Also double check your request URL, there is a chance you put a space there by accident